# Singular homology with coefficients in a ring versus in an abelian group

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

As described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4339851/1005113) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology#Coefficients_in_R) the singular homology of a topological space $X$ *with coefficients in a ring $R$* is given by a bunch of *$R$-modules* $H_n(X,R)$.

However, [sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) I see people talking about the homology groups $H_n(X,A)$ of a topological space $X$ *with coefficients in an abelian group* $A$. For instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology#Singular_cohomology) it says:

> In what follows, the coefficient group $A$ is sometimes not written. It is common to take $A$ to be a commutative ring $R$; then the cohomology groups are $R$-modules. A standard choice is the ring $\mathbb Z$ of integers.

My first confusion is: if $A$ is supposed to be an abelian group, how can one instantiate $A$ with a commutative ring $R$? A commutative ring is a completely different type of object than an abelian group.

**Question:** How does singular homology with coefficients in a ring relate to singular homology with coefficients in an abelian group? Is one of these concepts more general?

Comment: A ring is an abelian group under addition?

Comment: An Abelian group is a Z-module, so you take R to be Z. In general, for the definition of $C_n(X,\mathbb Z)$you define a simplex to be a map $\Delta^n \to X$ and then take free $\mathbb Z$-module on that set of simplices. More generally, you take the free $R$-module on those simplices and proceed exactly as before. The free R-module is formed by taking formal R linear combinations of those simplices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is a ring, it has an underlying abelian group : just forget the multiplication and the $1$. It is common to denote this underlying abelian group by the same symbol (here $R$) and use phrases such as "we view $R$ as an abelian group".

In particular, singular homology with coefficients in a ring is a special case of singular homology with coefficients in an abelian group.

However, the extra structure on $R$ affords extra structure on $H_n(X;R)$, namely that of an $R$-module . More generally, if $M$ is an $R$-module, then it also has an underlying abelian group and you can take $H_n(X;M)$ : this has the extra structure of an $R$-module too.

Overall, people tend to remove "forgetful" functors from the notation (so use the same letter for an $R$-module and its underlying abelian group, a ring and its underlying abelian group, etc.), at least the common ones.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question. One additional question: how do these two approaches (coefficients in abelian groups vs. in rings) relate to the machinery of homological algebra? It seems in homological algebra the object $T$ in an expression "$H_n(X,T)$" should always be an object of an *abelian category*. (See I.§6.1 and II.§5.1 in Gelfand and Manin's *Methods of Homological Algebra*.) However, the category of rings isn't an abelian category. So taking coefficients in rings is unnatural from the point of view of homological algebra, right?

Comment: $H_n(X;R)$ is an $R$-module, and does not have a natural ring structure . In fact, you can really think of $R$ as an $R$-module in $H_n(X;R)$, it's just the "most important one" (for an $R$-module $M$, $H_n(X;M)$ can somehow be "deduced" from $H_n(X;R)$ via things like the universal coefficient theorem when $R$ is a PID)

Comment: Thanks, that makes much sense!